# Update currentIndex title when page is turned over in storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, uistoryboardsegue, uipageviewcontroller

Using navigation controller as rootviewcontroller in storyboard. i want to update currentIndex when page is turned over. Storyboard push segue is displaying this pdfviewcontroller scene in which i m first trying to display title.

```
- (void) displaycurrentIndex:(NSUInteger)currentIndex {

self.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                              @"Page %i of %i",
                                              currentIndex,
                                             CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf)];

}
```

Pageviewcontroller other class have datasource methods to display pages of pdf in forward and reverse direction in pdfviewcontroller class

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController 
  viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
   viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

Tried this methods in pdfviewcontroller but not working

```
 - (void)updatecurrentpagenumber {

if (currentIndex == CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf) - 1) {

    [self displaycurrentIndex:currentIndex + 1];

}

//page = [modelArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex + 1];

else if  (currentIndex == 0) {

    [self displaycurrentIndex:currentIndex - 1];
}
//page = [modelArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex - 1];

 }
```

EDIT:

Tried this too but still it is not updating currentIndex

```
- (void)updatecurrentIndex:(NSUInteger)currentIndex {

totalPages = (int)CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf);

if (currentIndex<totalPages -1)
{
     [self displaycurrentIndex:currentIndex + 1];
}
else
{
    [self displaycurrentIndex:currentIndex - 1];
}
```

Thanks for help.